# Should i rewrite this LISP macro or modify it?

Tags: macros, common-lisp

I try to write a macro, which given a name could be supplied in the function *myfunc* to create a class and make an instance of this class.

Here is the code:

```
(defmacro define-class (class-name)
  `(eval
    `(progn
       (defclass ,,class-name () ())
   (make-instance ,class-name))))

(defun myfunc (name)
   (define-class name))
```

I can compile successfully the macro but not the function. In this case I get a warning at compilation time saying that:

```
undefined variable: CLASS-NAME
```

If I modify a bit the macro so that instead of writing

```
   (make-instance ,class-name)
```

I write

```
(make-instance ,,class-name)
```

Then in this case I can compile both, but when running *(myfunc 'toto)* I get the following error:

```
The variable TOTO is unbound.
```

I try to figure out how the macro is expanded with *macroexpand-1*. With the first macro which is defined with *(make-instance ,class-name)* it gave me the following result:

```
(EVAL `(PROGN (DEFCLASS ,'TOTO NIL NIL) (MAKE-INSTANCE ,CLASS-NAME)))
```

Whereas in the second macro which is defined with *(make-instance ,,class-name) it gave me the following result:

```
(EVAL `(PROGN (DEFCLASS ,'TOTO NIL NIL) (MAKE-INSTANCE ,'TOTO)))
```

But I guess the right expansion in my case would be something like:

```
(EVAL `(PROGN (DEFCLASS ,'TOTO NIL NIL) (MAKE-INSTANCE 'TOTO)))
```

How could I modify or re-write the macro so that it works?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve that requires you to define a new class in a function at run-time?

Comment: I try to call a macro in a function with one parameter. The parameter is used by the macro in two different situations. One with make-instance and one with defclass.

Comment: It should work if you change to `(make-instance ',,class-name)`, but I'm having hard time imagining a situation where this is a good thing to do.

Comment: thank you. it works. I'm not sure to really understand why, but it works. Following your comment I will try to re-write the way it is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to write code like this:

```
(defun myfunc (name)
  (define-class name))
```

This would actually be similar to this:

```
(defun myfunc (name)
  (let ((name name))
    (eval `(defclass ,name () ()))
    (make-instance name)))
```

Thus the `DEFINE-CLASS` macro should generate something like above code.

```
(defmacro define-class (name)
  (let ((name-sym (gensym "CLASS-NAME")))
    `(let ((,name-sym ,name))
       (eval `(defclass ,,name-sym () ()))
       (make-instance ,name-sym))))
```

Using it:

```
CL-USER 21 > (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(define-class name)))

(LET ((#:CLASS-NAME22897 NAME))
  (EVAL `(DEFCLASS ,#:CLASS-NAME22897 NIL NIL))
  (MAKE-INSTANCE #:CLASS-NAME22897))

CL-USER 22 > (myfunc 'baz42)
#<BAZ42 40202BBE73>
```

**But then, there is no reason that it should be a macro!**

A normal function is just fine...

```
(defun create-class-and-instance (name)
  (eval `(defclass ,name () ()))
  (make-instance name))
```

Answer (score 0):

The *defclass* macro generally expands into a call to the actual implementation-dependent function that creates the class. If you can call that function instead, you can get rid of *eval*. This is a little more direct and keeps the current lexical environment.

If you load the [closer-mop](https://github.com/pcostanza/closer-mop) system, you can write your function as follows:

```
(defun make-instance-from-new-class (class-name)
  (make-instance (closer-mop:ensure-class class-name)))
```